# How to fix iOS 7-8 safari prevent touchmove bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari

I have found a strange bug in iOS 7-8 Safari browser.

I set `preventDefault()` for touchmove event for all elements on the page.
At first all looks good, but in Safari in bottom of window, where navigation bar appear, when this bar is hidden, if i try to scroll page in that place - page will scroll with ignoring `preventDefault` for touchmove event.

How I can fix that?

Here is a demo. I set 3 seconds delay for `preventDefault()`, because you need scroll page slightly down in order to navigation bar became hidden.

[sanex3339.github.io/safariWTFISGOINGONo](http://sanex3339.github.io/safariWTFISGOINGON)

Comment: Hello - were you able to solve this?